# How to create a javascript function that can determine whether a file has been updated on time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I'd like to create a javascript function that can return 'Success' or 'Fail' based on whether a file has been modified after the most recent 9AM

- If it's 8:30AM on 1/2/18 but the file has been updated at 9:30AM on
  1/1/18, it should return 'Success'
- If it's 9:50AM on 1/2/18 but the file has been updated at 9:30AM on 1/1/18, it should return 'Fail' since it should have been updated by 9AM

I can attain the modified date time of the ile, and here's my attempt to create this function:

```
function determine_if_file_has_been_updated_since_9AM(modified_date_time){
var d = new Date();
most_recent_9am_time = d.setHours(9);

if (modified_date_time > most_recent_9am_time){
   return 'Success'
}
else {
return 'Fail'
}
```

}

However, this does not work if it's 830AM since the function will return False on the first scenario I mentioned above.

Comment: what is the type of `modified_date_time` and the formatting thereof?

Comment: Your modified_date_time must match the same format of getDate(), which is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. Hence, you will need to convert your 8:30AM into an equivalent number. You will need not only a time, but also a full date, at which that time.

Comment: You need a check for `d.getHours() >=9` before you modify `d`. To be honest this is all pretty simple math and comparisons. Work it out with  paper and pencil first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the time to number using `getTime()` and then compare.

```
modified_date_time.getTime()
```

By the way, it is much better if your function return `true`/`false` instead of string `Sucess`/`Fail`.
You should leave formatting to the UI code.